# cast objects to a known interface with generic type parameter where that type parameter is given as type variable at runtime

Tags: c#, types, reflection, casting

I am doing some reflection stuff. I have the following situation:

- I have a variable `Type myType` with some runtime value (e.g. `string` or `List<int>`).
- I have two variables `object a` and `object b` for which I know that they are of type `IImmutableSet<myType>`. (So if `myType=string` they'd be `IImmutableSet<string>`, if `myType=List<int>` they'd be `IImmutableSet<List<int>>` and so on.)

**How can I cast them?**

---

Motivation:

I want to do a comparison of `a` and `b` by content, i,e.

- check that both their size is equal. For that, I need a `Count` property (or equivalent property/method).
- check that `a` contains all elements of `b`. For that, I need a `Contains(...)` method.

If I had `ISet<T>`s, I'd just cast them to `ICollection` and use that interface's `Count` and `Contains(...)`.

But since `IImmutableSet<T>` does not implement any non-generic collection interface, I need to cast `a` and `b` to `IImmutableSet<myType>` (or `IReadOnlyCollection<myType>`). That syntax doesn't work because it expects a compile-time constant type.

--

Another thought... if casting isn't possible, I'd be happy with being able to call the said methods. Since I'm already doing heavy reflection, I don't care about speed.

Comment: Write a generic method that accepts the objects. Use reflection to craft a call to that method. That then gets you on the "other side of the looking glass" where you can just use your generic type parameter.

Comment: I'd question why you have them as `object` in the first place, that may be a code smell